# Getting nilClass <noMethod error. hav an array of numbers from a .index call, but cannot add to them?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, indexing

When I try to change an array item I get errors about there not being  + method?
Please help.

```
nameChar = [ '_','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n',
    'o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9' ]
name = File.open('read.txt', &:readline)
rname = name.split('')
ref =  []
newRef = []
bump = 0
rname.each do |let|
    ref << nameChar.index(let)
end
puts ref
ref[0] += 1
ref.each do |numb|
    numb = numb + bump 
    if numb > 36
        bump = 1
        numb = 0
    else
        bump = 0
    end
    newRef << numb
end
```

The error message is : new.rb:13:in 'block in ': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: What are you trying to do with this script? There's surely an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below part is suspicious:

```
rname.each do |let|
    ref << nameChar.index(let)
end
puts ref
ref[0] += 1
ref.each do |numb|
  numb = numb + bump
```

`nameChar.index(let)` any time found some characters that is not in your array `nameChar`.So `ref` has `nil` value in `ref[0]` position or any where inside the array `ref`.Because [**Array#index(ob)**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-index) returns `nil`,if `obj` not found.Now as `NilClass` has no `+` method,thus you are getting legitimate error.Use `p ref` to see what it contains,and make correction in your code.

Comment: While I think you care correct about the problem, I think you have to check the values of `numb` rather than just `ref[0]`. The exception is in the block, so may not necessarily be the first character that fails.

Comment: @JustinKo You are correct.. I added it,any how I couldn't see that second `+` for some reasons...But thanks for pointing me out there..

Comment: Thank you looked at what I was getting from the file and the string had a \n newline char at the end of it. used gsub to get rid of it and all is good in the universe. thanks